# PowerBI slicer value passing to query

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a report generated from a SQL query, having a due date column. My requirement is to create a slicer and  whatever the date a user selects in the slicer the report should show all the data where due date is less than the selected slicer date.

I am not able to pass the slicer date to my SQL query.

Can you guide me guys in finding the best possible way?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in general. Slicers and filters set on a report page cannot modify the model (e.g. calculated tables or calculated columns) and cannot modify the queries.

The only possible way to do this sort of thing is with a DirectQuery, which does it automatically in the background since it dynamically queries only the needed data. Otherwise, you need to pre-load all of the data that you intend to use in the report.

[Using DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-use-directquery) has significant limitations and may or may not work for your use case. Please check the limitations and considerations in the linked documentation for details.