# Pass parameters dynamically from Power BI to Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, dynamic, powerbi

I have a SQL stored procedure that grabs multiple billing information based on: Project Number, Project Manager and Billing Period.

Is there a way for end user to select the period, project number or manager and be shown all the billing information dynamically?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61638112/powerbi-slicer-value-passing-to-query/

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.